# SQL to return only 1 row per acct id

Tags: sql

How do I only return just one row per acct id?

I have a table similar to this:

| ID | Churn Decile | Churn Propensity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 9 Decile | Low Churn Propensity |
| 1 | 6 Decile | Mid Churn Propensity |
| 2 | 1 Decile | High Churn Propensity |
| 2 | 3 Decile | High Churn Propensity |

I want to keep just one row, I don't care which. Final table should look like:

| ID | Churn Decile | Churn Propensity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 9 Decile | Low Churn Propensity |
| 2 | 3 Decile | High Churn Propensity |

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by id order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```